# How can I save a session in a directory owned by root?

Tags: sessions

I quite often open linux system configuration files with vim and sometimes  have a session with lots of tabs, splits, quicklists etc that I want to save to a session and restore again later.
The problem is I usually only open as a non-root user with read-only access and therefore my vim process doesn't have privileges to save the `Session.vim` file in the current directory (I guess it may be able to save to home - but My preference is to save the session file to the site where I'm working).
Is it possible to elevate to `sudo` privileges inside vim simply for the `:mksession` command?

Comment: Why don't you simply do all that as root, as intended?

Comment: @romainl Im not sure I understand, do you mean `:! sudo vim -exec "mksession"` or something like that?

Comment: No. Edit system files as root.

Comment: you mean like in my answer below?

Comment: No, I mean editing those files as root, not as a regular user. That's how you are supposed to do it.

Comment: Oh you mean I should have just launched vim as root to begin with ? 4 times out of 5 I only want to look at those config files - so going in without root privileges is my safety mechanism to prevent me accidentally changing something.

Comment: Editors are for *editing* files, if you only want to take a look, use a pager like `less`. As for "sessions", take a look at `screen`, `tmux`or `detach`.

Comment: You should run Vim as user. Store you sessions in your own directory. If you need to edit some root-owned files use `sudo` hacks. Something like this:
`cmap w!! sudo tee % > /dev/null %`

Comment: I prefer to edit files as my own user, as that will load all my plugins. Also this way it is simpler for me when I work on servers where i don't have root access.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit hacky, so I'd be interested if anyone else has a better answer, but I was able to achieve this inside vim with:

- `:! sudo touch Session.vim`
- `:! sudo chown user:user Session.vim`
- `:mksession Session.vim` or `:Obsess` (because I'm using tim popes `vim-obsession` plugin)